# Problem with doubled UVs and Textures

Tags: texturing, uv

I am working with some models, and most of them come like this, with a line in the middle that delimits the model in this two uvs. What's happening here?

[image]

Comment: what line in the middle? I guess as your textures are symmetrical, these are the 2 parts (left and right) of the UVs, the left being inverted, it would be exactly the same if you put the left part on the image except the UVs would overlap, which is not convenient

Comment: There is no "line" by itself, but if I move the left group around, only the left side of the model will change texture.

Comment: yes; because the left group is the left part of your object?

Comment: Shouldn't just be one group?

Comment: Without knowing your file, it looks like you have an object, that is using UDIM tiles for your UVs.
See the Blender manual for this topic: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/workflows/udims.html

Comment: could you please pack the images and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes, of course. https://pasteall.org/blend/3109482a96624404a8d3a6b8ca0eefe1

Comment: so yes, as I thought, if you select the left part of the character in the 3D view it will select the left group of UVs, and vice-versa, the left group wil use the exact same image, except it is inverted compared to the right group so that the texture appears symmetrical on the 3D object

Comment: What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.

Comment: @Cpt-Proxy, it's not clear why it is a problem for you, maybe elaborate. If you want to see the picture under the left part, open the N panel > View tab > Repeat Image option. The texture image is implicitely repeating, that's why you don't see a black texture on the left side.